# Adding a new value to the drop down list box

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list box which has one of the values to be others. I want to move these value to the last. Please help me with this. The code i am using is as follows

```
ddlAssetsCountryOthersone.DataSource = lstIMAssetsByCountryOthers;
ddlAssetsCountryOthersone.DataTextField = "AssetDescription";
ddlAssetsCountryOthersone.DataValueField = "AssetDescription";
ddlAssetsCountryOthersone.DataBind();
ddlAssetsCountryOthersone.Items.Remove(
             ddlAssetsCountryOthersone.Items.FindByValue(
                Constants.PhilosophyAndEmphasis.Other.ToString()));
```

How can i add the others back to the drop down list in the last

Comment: i'll bet if anyone understands what you are trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this after your databind :

```
ddlAssetsCountryOthersone.Items.Add(new ListItem("Others", "Others"));
```

By the way if you use Insert method, you can insert the item you want to the position you want. For example the code below adds the Other option to the 4th order :

```
ddlAssetsCountryOthersone.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem("Others", "Others"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you the dropdownlist is databound you will not be able to add items to your control after the `DataBind()` call, and if you add them before they will be cleared anyway whe you call `DataBind()`.

You can use `Insert` or `Add` after the data binding takes place, and you can specify the index of the item you're inserting. `Insert` is used to insert at the specific location, `Add` will append to the bottom, as in your case:

```
//after databind

//example with insert - (-1 as list is zero based)
ddlMyList.Items.Insert(noOfItems-1, "Other");
```

OR

```
//add
ddlMyList.Items.Add("Other");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like

```
ListItem li = new ListItem("text", "value");
    yourDropdown.Items.Insert(yourDropdown.Items.Count, li);
```

If you have 5 items in dropdown, it will return 5, since the insert index start from 0

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
ListItem li = ddlAssetsCountryOthersone.FindByValue(Constants.PhilosophyAndEmphasis.Other.ToString()));
ddlAssetsCountryOthersone.Remove(li);
ddlAssetsCountryOthersone.Add(li);
```

That should work, please test - and replace Add with Insert as per JohnIdol's suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

When databinding, it is far easier to add/remove items from the list that is being databound than it is to add/remove items after the data binding takes place.

I would create a wrapper around `lstIMAssetsByCountryOthers` that makes the necessary changes into a new `IEnumberable` and returns that new object to be databound.