# How to set value in drop down on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set the value of drop down on the click event.  The drop down list is in side the form view.

How to set value in drop down in button click?(Button is also indside the form view)
Thanks

Comment: please post some code you have tried.........

Comment: Refer these link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741736/adding-a-new-value-to-the-drop-down-list-box for more help post some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider ur dropdown is ddl trhe on button click

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    ddl.item.FindByValue("yourvalue").selected = true;

//or
    ddl.selectedindex=0;//will set first value. 

    }
```